# MATLAB: Error in Using 'fminsearch' function

Tags: matlab, fminsearch

I am doing a small research that requires to find the argmin of some function. This is the function I wrote. I want to find a vector x that gives the minimum output of this function. I tried `fminsearch(@crc,x)`, but I got the following
error.

```
Error in fminsearch (line 200)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});
```

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

```
function crc = SQ(x)
pdfx = gampdf([0:89],x(1),1/x(2));
pdfy =  gampdf([0:89],x(3),1/x(4));
pdfz = conv(pdfx,pdfy);
cdfz= cumsum(pdfz);
h=pdfz./(1-cdfz);
% I = piecewise(0<t<=9, 0.1, 9<t<=14, 0.3, 14<t<=19, 0.9, ...
% 19<t<=24, 1.5, 19<t<=29, 3,  29<t<=34, 5.7, 34<t<=39, 10.5, 39<t<=44, 19,...
% 44<t<=49, 33.1, 49<t<=54, 59.5, 54<t<=59, 68.4, 59<t<=64, 90.2, 64<t<=69,...
% 121.4, 69<t<=74, 153, 74<t<=79, 197.5, 79<t<=84, 237.9, 84<t<=89, 258.8);
I=zeros(1,161);
for t=0:1:89
if 0 < t && t <= 9
        I(t)=.1;
elseif 9<t&& t <=14
        I(t) = 0.3;
elseif 14<t && t<=19 
        I(t) = 0.9;
elseif 19<t&& t <=24
        I(t) = 1.5;
elseif 24<t&& t <=29
        I(t) = 3;
elseif 29<t&& t <=34
        I(t) = 5.7;
elseif 34<t&& t <=39
        I(t) = 10.5;
elseif 39<t&& t <=44
        I(t) = 19;
elseif 44<t&& t <=49
        I(t) = 33.1;
elseif 49<t&& t <=54
        I(t) = 59.5;
elseif 54<t&& t <=59
        I(t) = 68.4;
elseif 59<t&& t <=64
        I(t) = 90.2;
elseif 64<t&& t <=69
        I(t) = 121.4; 
elseif 69<t&& t <=74
        I(t) = 153;
elseif 74<t&& t <=79
        I(t) = 197.5; 
elseif 79<t&& t <=84
        I(t) = 237.9;
elseif 84<t&& t <=89
        I(t) = 258.8;        
     
end
end
I=I/100000;
sqer = sum((h([20:89])-I([20:89])).^2);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The error massage you posted looks incompleted. It will be clearer if you show us the full error message.
Your function is called `SQ`; `crc` is the name of its output variable.
Note also that matlab identifies functions by their file names. I assume your function file is named `SQ.m`.
Try

```matlab
fminsearch(@SQ,x)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Thant's supper helpful! Thank you!